# Toggle D3 shape depending on Boolean

Tags: javascript, meteor, d3.js

I am trying to toggle between showing and hiding a D3 shape in Meteor, depending on the value of a Boolean, saved in a Session.  My code is in this [Meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/F6XBPKw37iWunYZaM/D3%20toggle).

If I change the value of the Session in the code manually and reload, the shapes will toggle.  However, I can't get the shapes to toggle when I change by clicking the buttons, since the template does not re-render.

**EDIT - RESOLVED:**

Updated final [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/p734GSBxRpG2MgP9e/D3%20Toggle%20(FINAL))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context of `Template.Main.onRendered` is not reactive - that's why your code is not being executed on `Session` changes.

Change this:

```
Template.Main.onRendered(function () {
    const self = this;

    ...
});
```

to this:

```
Template.Main.onRendered(function () {
    const self = this;

    this.autorun(function () {
        // reactive context here
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  Realized I also needed to add code to remove the elements, but all works great now.  Posted updated MeteorPad above.